# abort_with_payload : app built with Xcode 13.2.1 crash after launch on iOS12.5 (real device only)

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, ios12

The app crashes when users download from AppStore and try to open the app, it shows launch screen and then crashes.

This happens only with real devices running iOS12.* App was built with Xcode 13.2.1.

Simulators and real devices running iOS13 and above are fine.

This is what the crash log obtained:

```
#0  (null) in __abort_with_payload ()
#5  (null) in _dyld_start ()
```

Update: see this [thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/696990)

Comment: Turn out downgrading XCode to 13.1 works. See this [forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/696990).

Answer (score 0):

> Some times it happened for target iOS and build iOS(i.e : target 9.0 but build 12.0)version and also change to "Embed & Sign" to "Embed without Signing" under General > Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content. You will try to change your target and build ios version in same.